# Move boot partition from one internal hard drive to another

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootloader

I recently bought an SSD and installed Windows 7 on it, however it didn't install exactly how I intended - it still requires my HDD to be plugged in to boot onto the SSD.

Hopefully the following image explains my situation a bit better. My SSD is the C: drive, and the old HDD is D: - this drive has a 100MB partition which contains the boot sector that requires the HDD for booting into Windows.

[image: Partitions]

From what I've found out, booting from the Windows 7 install DVD and running startup repair will resolve the issue. However, as every situation is different (and I'm particularly paranoid I'll somehow brick my system), I wanted to be sure this was correct.

So, what's the best way to get my SSD to boot without requiring the HDD to be present?

Comment: Unplug your HDD, and then use the Windows repair to fix the C: drive.  If you're REALLY paranoid about it, then a) make backups b) take it to a professional.

Comment: @techie007 Thanks, I did figure that was the way to do it. As for that other question - I did check that out, and whilst it does seem similar the only thing I wasn't sure about was the extra System Reserved partition on my HDD.